# How do I pass variables through different classes or root widgets in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm creating an app where I determine a variable in one class and need to transfer it to a different class. I wanted to use id but that doesn't work for different root widgets. Then I found out about factory and it seemed promising and it seems to work somewhat but when I update the variable in the PopupColor class it doesn't update in my DrawScreen class.

Here's the code.

py:

```
class PopupColor(Popup):
    color = [0,0,0,1]
    def on_press_dismiss(self, colorpicker, *args):
        print(self.color)
        self.dismiss()
        self.color = colorpicker.color
        print(self.color)

class DrawScreen(Screen):
    def testy(self):
        self.color = Factory.PopupColor().color
        print(self.color)
```

kv:

```
<PopupColor>:
    title: 'Pick a Color'
    size_hint: 0.75, 0.75
    id: popupcolor

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 5
        spacing: 5
        orientation: 'vertical'

        ColorPicker:
            id: colorpicker
            size_hint: 1.0, 1.0

        Button:
            text: 'Choose Color'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_release: popupcolor.on_press_dismiss(colorpicker)

<DrawScreen>: 

    Button:
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        font_size: 30
        text: "Back"
        on_release: Factory.PopupColor().open()

    ColorButton:
        text: "Test"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "y":0.1}
        on_release: root.testy()
```

So how can I do this and how far off am I?

EDIT: So it seems like the error isn't really the factory part but more so that the variable in PopupColor doesn't change permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you change the attribute, you use `self`, which refers to this instance.
But since you create a new `PopupColor` object, each time you open the popup, you need to treat `color` as a shared variable.
So you could change color like this:

```
PopupColor.color = colorpicker.color
```

That way you treat the attribute `color` as shared with all `PopupColor` objects.